# Prepared statement not sending to database

Tags: php, html, image, prepared-statement

I am attempting to create my first prepared statement. With this I am also trying to send my first image file to be moved into my database. I have been working on this for a month or so and cannot get this to work. I initially was trying to do this with a simple insert command with php and everything was inserting into my db except for the name of the img file. I was told numerous times to create this with a prepared statement, so I am doing that, but nothing is sending to my data base and I cannot figure out why.

I start my code with validation for some of the data fields. I am not validating the img file yet, but will later. The validation is not the issue as I broke this down a bit and it is passing through it.

I do not have any errors that are occurring. I even put in something that would generate any syntax errors when executing the statement, but that does not generate any errors.

Does any one see what I'm doing wrong here that would cause this to not send? Does it have to do with my img file or am I doing the prepared statement incorrectly?

```
if($validation->passed()) {
        if(isset($_POST['create'])){ 
            $product_id = trim( $_POST['product_id'] );
            $name = trim( $_POST['name'] );
            $price = trim( $_POST['price'] );
            $saleprice = trim( $_POST['saleprice'] );
            $final_price = trim( $_POST['final_price'] );
            $shippingprice = trim( $_POST['shippingprice'] );
            $category = trim( $_POST['category'] );
            $item_details = trim( $_POST['item_details'] );
            $item_details2 = trim( $_POST['item_details2'] );
            $description = trim( $_POST['description'] );
            $viewproduct_type = trim( $_POST['viewproduct_type'] );
            $file = "productpics/". $_FILES['file']['name']; // save the filename

        }else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file); // move the file

        //Connection
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");
        /* check connection */
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }



        /* create a prepared statement */
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO products (product_id, name, price, saleprice, final_price, shippingprice, category, item_details, item_details2, description, viewproduct_type, date, img) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)")) {


            /* bind parameters for markers */
            $stmt->bind_param('isiiiissssss', $product_id, $name, $price, $saleprice, $final_price, $shippingprice, $category, $item_details, $item_details2, $description, $viewproduct_type, $file);

            /* execute query */
            $stmt->execute();

            //if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$con->error, E_USER_WARNING);}


        /* close statement */
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            }
        }
    }
 }
}   
?>
```

The form

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="product_id">Product ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="product_id" class="smallinputbar" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="name">Product Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="price">Product Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="price" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="saleprice">Sale Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="saleprice">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="final_price">Final Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="final_price" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="shippingprice">Shipping Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="shippingprice" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="category" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="item_details">Item Details</label>
        <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="item_details" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="item_details2">Item Details 2</label>
        <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="item_details2">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="description" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="viewproduct_type">View Product Type</label>
        <select class="optionbar" name="viewproduct_type">
            <option value="Not Selected">Not Selected</option>
            <option value="a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id">Standard</option>
            <option value="Option">Option</option>
        </select>
    </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
            <label for="button">
            <input type="submit" id="button" name="create" value="Create New Product">
            </label>

            <span class="floatright">
                <input type="file" name="file" class="inputbarfile">
                <input type="submit" name="create" id="signinButton" value="Upload">
            </span>
</form>
```

Update showing full code with validation:

```
<?php
//Validation
if(Input::exists()) {
if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'product_id' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 1,
            'max' => 50,
            'unique' => 'products'
        ),
        'name' => array (
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 50
        ),
        'price' => array (
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 1,
            'max' => 50
        ),
        'saleprice' => array (
            'min' => 1,
            'max' => 50
        ),
        'final_price' => array (
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 1,
            'max' => 50
        ),
        'shippingprice' => array (
            'max' => 50
        ),
        'category' => array (
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 50
        ),
        'item_details' => array (
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 1550
        ),
        'item_details2' => array (
            'max' => 1550
        ),
        'description' => array (
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 1550
        )

    )
    );
 //Create

    if($validation->passed()) {
        if(isset($_POST['create'])){ 
            $product_id = trim( $_POST['product_id'] );
            $name = trim( $_POST['name'] );
            $price = trim( $_POST['price'] );
            $saleprice = trim( $_POST['saleprice'] );
            $final_price = trim( $_POST['final_price'] );
            $shippingprice = trim( $_POST['shippingprice'] );
            $category = trim( $_POST['category'] );
            $item_details = trim( $_POST['item_details'] );
            $item_details2 = trim( $_POST['item_details2'] );
            $description = trim( $_POST['description'] );
            $viewproduct_type = trim( $_POST['viewproduct_type'] );
            $file = "productpics/". $_FILES['file']['name']; // save the filename

        }else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file); // move the file

        //Connection
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");
        /* check connection */
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }



        /* create a prepared statement */
        $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO products (product_id, name, price, saleprice, final_price, shippingprice, category, item_details, item_details2, description, viewproduct_type, date, img) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)") 


            /* bind parameters for markers */
            $stmt->bind_param('isiiiissssss', $product_id, $name, $price, $saleprice, $final_price, $shippingprice, $category, $item_details, $item_details2, $description, $viewproduct_type, $file);

            /* execute query */
            if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$con->error, E_USER_WARNING);}


        /* close statement */
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        }
    }
 }
 }   
 ?>
```

Comment: you're not checking for errors on your query like I told you to use in your other question. You commented that out, why? and using what I put in my answer. No errors or is that irrelevant?

Comment: I did check. It didn't throw any errors, so I commented it out in this to show that I checked for that.

Comment: try removing the conditional statement for `if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con...` then replace that with `$stmt = $con->prepare(...` see if that makes any difference. Or, try a simple "one entry" query rather than a whole bunch. Once that works, build from there. Once you hit a snag, you'll know what to go after.

Comment: I'd also check to see if this works to start with `if($validation->passed()) {` and your first body of code seems to be missing 2x closing braces `}` if that's the whole code for it. I also see 2x inputs bearing the same `name="create"` attribute, so that's questionable.

Comment: I've made edits to my comments above, reload them. That last one especially.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added more of my code to show how I have this set up. I'm in the middle of trying to change it to $stmt = $con->prepare(....    as you suggested, so the bottom looks a little rough right now. But, the validation is working properly. I tested it with a simple echo and else statement to show if it failed. It came back passing. Although it then showed errors because I took out the variables to do the test.

Comment: You see this `<input type="submit" id="button" name="create" value="Create New Product">` and this `<input type="submit" name="create" id="signinButton" value="Upload">` those have the same "name" attributes, and I have no idea why and how you're using them, if one at a time, or together. This `if(isset($_POST['create'])){` is to work for one of them. Depending which input you use.

Comment: Are you referring to in the form where I have the image upload and the one for sending the data? I'm not sure how else to structure that.

Comment: How would you suggest I make it work so when I submit the data the img file is sent with it? I don't know how to make the img file send with it other wise. I want all of it to send together.

Comment: exactly. the image upload button and the Create new product inputs have the same "name" attribute, which I don't know why. there might be conflict here. Like I said, try one query entry rather than a whole bunch. Do an upload method apart and see.

Comment: I changed the prepare to $stmt = $con->prepare....and it is now throwing an error for my bind_param line....Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$stmt' (T_VARIABLE) in /home4/pfarley1/public_html/addproduct.php on line 111........By the way I still have the error code in the execute line in my file.

Comment: Try replacing `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");` with `$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","bfb");` see if that makes a difference. Plus, given the line number to which the error is in being line 111, doesn't correspond with your "full" code. There's only 108 lines in there. Also make sure you've chosen the right database and table. I honestly don't know why this would be failing along with the `$stmt' (T_VARIABLE)` error. You sure that code you're using is exactly that?

Comment: I found the error. You have a missing semi-colon `;` at the end of this line `$stmt = $con->prepare..........NOW(), ?)")` <= right there. In conjunction with the comment just above about `$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","bfb");`

Comment: Added the semi colon, but still not getting anything to send. The number of lines aren't matching up exactly because I have 15 lines of code before the validation code starts. Yes, the code is exactly that other than my real connection.

Comment: Well at this point Paul I am out of ideas. All I can suggest is to remove the class stuff, make up a new form with one or two inputs in a new db/table, then try a straight query with 2 prepared statements. Once you've gotten those to work, build up from there, then add your class in there. Once you see something suddenly makes things stop, you'll know what's causing it. If you've any fancy stuff; don't use it. Nothing like `$validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(` which I suspect may be the cause here, or not helping it. Once you've gotten regular prepared statements going, you'll know.

Comment: My file is configured with a php framework. I added in debugging before in my db class and I just went in and added echos to it. It shows the query is working, but not successful?   DEBUG DB::query called
SQL: SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = ?

PARAMS: 3573
DEBUG: prepared statment created ok
DEBUG: query succeeded, rowcount was: 0